# how to move cptscatterplot line little forward

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot, scatter-plot, xcode7.2

I have implemented cptscatterplot lines.In my app, i have bars under labels and based on yvalues cptscatterplot line will be drawn.

If value is empty then i am breaking the line and continuing again if value is valid, but the line ends with starting point of the bar that bit confusing whether it is valid or not.

can some one help me that can we move line to middle of the bars, i mean starting/ending the line in the middle of the bar.

Thanks in advance. Please help me regarding this struggling alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move either the bars or the scatter plot line. To move the bars, use the `barOffset` property or add an offset to the bar locations. To move the scatter plot, add an offset to the x-values of the plot.

Comment: thanks for the reply...i am able to move bars but not able to scatter plot line. can you please give any sample to move the scatter plot line that helps me alot.

Comment: i tried by adding offset to x-labels but not working...Can you please help me where i need to add exactly to move the scatter line

Comment: In the datasource, add the offset to whatever the the value for the `CPTScatterPlotFieldX` field would be. Do this for every data point to move the whole line.

Comment: Yes figured out Eric Skroch..Thanks for reply..If we have one valid data point then can we have drawn line?

Comment: It takes at least two points to draw a line. The plot will draw plot symbols at any visible points no matter how many there are.